# Creating a new column based on a composed condition on multiple columns

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a dataset, a polygon, with several columns, let's say:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1120 | 1121 | 9180 |
| 1120 | 1120 | 9180 |
| 1120 | 1121 | 9190 |
| 1130 | 2250 | 1120 |
| 1220 | 1131 | 9180 |

What I need is an `if` function that creates a 4th column if any column (1, 2 or all of them), from 1 to 3, matches a condition.

The condition is multiple. In this case it would be any column `= 1120 OR 9180 OR 2250`.

So the fourth column looks like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1120 | 1121 | 9180 | YES |
| 1120 | 1120 | 9180 | YES |
| 1121 | 1121 | 9190 | NO |
| 1130 | 2250 | 1121 | YES |
| 1221 | 1131 | 9190 | NO |

I **REALLY** struggle with `if` statements if they are multiple I get mad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want as your qgis field calculator expression is:

```
if(
  array_contains(
    array_foreach(
      array("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 2"),
      @element in (1120, 9180, 2250)
    ),
    TRUE
  ),
  'YES',
  'NO'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more straightforward, using [`array_intersect()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-intersect) function:

```
if (
    array_intersect ( 
        array (1120, 9180, 2250),
        array ("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 2")
    ),
    'Yes',
    'No'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the IF statement in the following way to get the results you need:

```
if(("Column1" IN (1120,9180,2250)) OR ("Column2" IN (1120,9180,2250)) OR ("Column3" IN (1120,9180,2250)),'YES','NO')
```

[image]